# Selecionar determinada quantidade de dados para cada tipo status

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, query

Billy Jow aqui!

Na minha tabela **historico** eu tenho um campo **status** que pode assumir quatro valores possíveis:

**'AVALIAR', 'FRACASSO', 'REAVALIAR', 'SUCESSO'**

Desejo selecionar 20 registros de cada status onde a data seja mais recente.
Sendo que desejo **apenas os status 'Fracasso', 'Reavaliar' e 'Sucesso'**.
Como ficaria minha query para retornar todos os campos?

campos importantes:
historico(codigo, data, status)

Comment: Já tentou um UNION com 4 `SELECT`?

Comment: Sim, chegou a retornar 50 de cada um, porém quando fiz a query pra retornar todos os campos da tabela não funcionou. Por algum motivo retorna menos valores para o fracasso.

Comment: Eu fiz uma resposta, a sua SQL do comentário se assemelha a essa ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT h.*
FROM historico h LEFT JOIN historico h2
    ON h.his_status = h2.his_status 
       AND (h.his_data < h2.his_data OR (h.his_data = h2.his_data AND h.his_codigo > h2.his_codigo))
WHERE h.his_status IN ('FRACASSO', 'REAVALIAR', 'SUCESSO')
GROUP BY h.his_codigo
HAVING COUNT(*) < 50
ORDER BY h.his_status, h.his_data DESC, h.his_codigo;
```

[Otimização de código SQL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/254561/otimiza%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-c%C3%B3digo-sql/254629#254629)

Comment: @VirgilioNovic O propósito da otimização do código é o desempenho. Volta lá na outra pergunta e leia meus comentários na resposta do Antony.

Comment: Comentario para VirgilioNovic, por dizer besteiras.
"O código na resposta que você deu eu já havia feito antes, porém com algum tipo de erro que não permitiu a execução, portanto não há solução na sua resposta. Você ainda editou para ficar igual a minha solução (com os parênteses). Quanto à redundância de resposta em duas perguntas, creio que isso não seja crime algum, pois o importante é manter o histórico para que outros venham ser ajudados. Você deve estar mais preocupado com sua pontuação no fórum e, por isso não está pensando na lógica das coisas. – Billly Jow 13/11 às 20:58 "

Answer (score 3):

Utilize o comando `SQL` `UNION ALL` ***exemplo***:

```
(SELECT codigo, data, status 
 FROM historico WHERE status = 'AVALIAR' ORDER BY DATA DESC LIMIT 20)
UNION ALL
(SELECT codigo, data, status 
 FROM historico WHERE status = 'FRACASO' ORDER BY DATA DESC LIMIT 20)
UNION ALL
(SELECT codigo, data, status 
 FROM historico WHERE status = 'REAVALIAR' ORDER BY DATA DESC LIMIT 20)
UNION ALL
(SELECT codigo, data, status 
 FROM historico WHERE status = 'SUCESSO' ORDER BY DATA DESC LIMIT 20)
```

Quando se utiliza o [UNION ALL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html), não faz distinção no resultado obtidos ([distinct](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html))  e traz tudo que aquela `SQL` satisfaça.

Essa dúvida seria a sua da pergunta, mas, no comentários precisa de todos os campos, então:

```
(SELECT * FROM historico WHERE status = 'AVALIAR' ORDER BY DATA DESC LIMIT 20)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM historico WHERE status = 'FRACASO' ORDER BY DATA DESC LIMIT 20)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM historico WHERE status = 'REAVALIAR' ORDER BY DATA DESC LIMIT 20)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM historico WHERE status = 'SUCESSO' ORDER BY DATA DESC LIMIT 20)
```

<sub>***Referencias***</sub>

- [13.2.9.3 UNION Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html)
- [SQL: Utilizando o Operador UNION e UNION ALL](https://www.devmedia.com.br/sql-utilizando-o-operador-union-e-union-all/37457)