# Otimização de código SQL

Tags: mysql, query, otimização

Como posso otimizar o seguinte código para não utilizar 3 SELECTs e não engessar a consulta a apenas 3 status

```
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM historico 
    WHERE 
        his_status = 'FRACASSO' 
    ORDER BY his_data DESC 
    LIMIT 50
)
UNION ALL
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM historico 
    WHERE 
        his_status = 'REAVALIAR' 
    ORDER BY his_data DESC 
    LIMIT 50
)
UNION ALL
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM historico 
    WHERE 
        his_status = 'SUCESSO' 
    ORDER BY his_data DESC 
    LIMIT 50
)
```

No momento tenho 2562 registros na tabela historico e estou utilizando todos para treinar uma RNA. Custa de 3 a 4 minutos. Esta consulta possibilitará o usuário informar quantas amostras de cada status deseja utilizar. A quantidade 50 é um exemplo. A otimização da query é também para diminuir o custo de tempo.

Comment: Sim, é válido usar in, desde que eu informe o intervalo pela aplicação, porém só poderá ser usado se a query for otimizada. Com apenas 1 select, pelo menos.

Comment: Não atentei para o limite tripo , 50 de cada caso.

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/254540/57801

Comment: Um índice talves ajude , usando o UNION mesmo , index his_data,his_status

Comment: Normalmente o UNION é uma solução razoável, o dinamismo pode ser produzido na linguagem cliente (quando houver). Talvez até fosse o caso de usar uma função ou procedure, mas usualmente não se justifica.

Comment: Resposta atualizada.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Eis uma alternativa capaz de trazer até 50 registros de cada `status` ordenados por data. Em caso de empate entre dois registros o resultado é desempatado por `id` (o menor `id` prevalece).

```
SELECT h.*
FROM historico AS h LEFT JOIN historico AS h2
    ON h.his_status = h2.his_status 
       AND (h.his_data < h2.his_data OR (h.his_data = h2.his_data AND h.id > h2.id))
WHERE h.his_status IN ('FRACASSO', 'REAVALIAR', 'SUCESSO')
GROUP BY h.id
HAVING COUNT(*) < 50
ORDER BY h.his_status, h.his_data DESC, h.id;
```

**Veja funcionando no [DB Fiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=23b6eef88a4682ad5ca19cce6b27d619)**

Essa versão é mais compacta. Você pode filtrar quantos `status` quiser. Pode inclusive remover a cláusula `where` para retornar os primeiro 50 resultados de todos os `status` da sua tabela.

Não tenho como comparar a *performance* dessa solução com a versão original com `UNION ALL`. Isso tem que ser feito com o seu *dataset* completo, com a exata mesma estrutura de tabelas e índices, na mesma versão do MySQL com as mesmas configurações. Dito isso o link acima mostra o plano de execução para uma pequena quantidade de dados na ausência de qualquer índice além daquele criado implicitamente pela PK, usando o MariaDB 10.2. Nessas condições a versão original está varrendo a tabela completa para cada `status` desejado. A versão acima, apesar de também varrer a tabela completa duas vezes e utilizar uma tabela temporária, o faz independentemente da quantidade de `status` no filtro.

Comment: Executei os testes rodando 5 vezes as três consultas e tirando uma média.
A minha leva entorno de 0,031s.
A do DVD leva entorno de 0,053s.
A sua nas 5 rodadas apresentou 0,00.
Realmente a existência de mais SELECTs na Query derruba a performance do banco.
Agadeço

Answer (score 10):

Você pode fazer desta maneira. Irá retornar apenas os registros com "linha" inferior ou igual a 50 (ou seja, 50 registros no máx. de cada tipo):

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(SELECT *,
    (@numero:=IF(@status = `his_status`,
     @numero+1,
     IF(@status := `his_status`, 1, 1))) linha 
  FROM historico a
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @numero:=0) b
  ORDER BY his_status, his_data DESC
) AS c 
WHERE c.linha <= 50;
```

SQLFiddle por indicação do amigo @Everson nos comentários: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e6166e/5/0

Comment: @Everson Atualizado.

Comment: @DvD Se quiser utilizar na sua resposta: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e6166e/3

Comment: Sua resposta está parcialmente correta, porém considere que um número vai ter que ser atribuído a todas as linhas. O que ocorrerá com a performance nesse caso?

Comment: @Sorack A resposta não tem foco na performance. É apenas uma sugestão funcional. Se alguém tiver outra resposta que possa abrangir funcionalidade e performance, seria interessante.

Comment: Pergunta atualizada.

Comment: @BilllyJow Fala! Se a edição da pergunta foi por causa de performance, veja este print com um resultado que fiz utilizando a query da resposta com uma tabela de mais de 51 mil registros, e levou apenas 0,18 segundos: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmjn3.png

Comment: Minha tabela historico possui 32 campos.
De qualquer forma, vou tentar utilizar seu código.